# Texture Buffer for OpenGL Video Player

Tags: multithreading, opengl, textures, video-processing

I am using OpenGL, Ffmpeg and SDL to play videos and am currently optimizing the process of getting frames, decoding them, converting them from YUV to RGB, uploading them to texture and displaying the texture on a quad. Each of these stages is performed by a seperate thread and they written to shared buffers which are controlled by SDL mutexes and conditions (except for the upload and display of the textures as they need to be in the same context).

I have the player working fine with the decode, convert and OpenGL context on seperate threads but realised that because the video is 25 frames per second, I only get a converted frame from the buffer, upload it to OpenGL and bind it/display it every 40 milliseconds in the OpenGL thread. The render loop goes round about 6-10 times not showing the next frame for every frame it shows, due to this 40ms gap.

Therefore I decided it might be a good idea to have a buffer for the textures too and set up an array of textures created and initialised with glGenTextures() and the glParameters I needed etc.

When it hasn't been 40ms since the last frame refresh, a method is ran which grabs the next converted frame from the convert buffer and uploads it to the next free texture in the texture buffer by binding it then calling glTexSubImage2D(). When it has been 40ms since the last frame refresh, a seperate method is ran which grabs the next GLuint texture from the texture buffer and binds it with glBindTexture(). So effectively, I am just splitting up what was being done before (grab from convert buffer, upload, display) into seperate methods (grab from convert buffer, upload to texture buffer | and | grab from texture buffer, display) to make use of the wasted time between 40ms refreshes.

Does this sound reasonable? Because when ran, the video halts all the time in a sporadic manner, sometimes about 4 frames are played when they are supposed to (every 40ms) but then there is a 2 second gap, then 1 frame is shown, then a 3 second gap and the video is totally unwatchable.

The code is near identical to how I manage the convert thread grabbing decoded frames from the decode buffer, converting them from YUV to RGB and then putting them into the convert buffer so can't see where the massive bottlenecking could be.

Could the bottlenecking be on the OpenGL side of things? Is the fact that I am storing new image data to 10 different textures the problem as when a new texture is grabbed from the texture buffer, the raw data could be a million miles away from the last one in terms of memory location on the video memory? That's my only attempt at an answer, but I don't know much about how OpenGL works internally so that's why I am posting here.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I'm no OpenGL expert, but my guess of the bottleneck is that the textures are intialized properly in system memory but are sent to the video memory at the 'wrong' time (like all at once instead of as soon as possible), stalling the pipeline. When using glTexSubImage2D you have no guarantees about when a texture arrives in video memory until you bind it.

Googling around it seems pixelbuffer objects give you more control about when they are in video memory: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=262523